# spawn random images with different speed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a space shooter where a plane comes down from the top of the screen this plane is called enemy.png but now i want to add more enemys. But i dont know where to start. 
I want to add another enemy that is called enemy1.png. this enemy also needs to have a different speed then enemy.png

Hope you guys can help.

This is the code for the enemy

```
//enemies
var enemy;
var enemyTotal = 5;
var enemies = [enemy1,enemy2];
var enemy_x = 50;
var enemy_y = -45;
var enemy_w = 50;
var enemy_h = 50;
var speed = 3;








//Build enemy array of x/y coordinate, width, height, and speed
for (var i = 0; i < enemyTotal; i++) {
enemies.push([enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_w, enemy_h, speed]);

  enemy_x += enemy_w + 60;
}

//Iterate through array of enemies and draw them on the canvas
function drawEnemies() {
  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(enemy, enemies[i][0], enemies[i][1]);

  }
}

//Iterate through array of enemies and update their position
function moveEnemies() {
  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    if (enemies[i][1] < height) {
      enemies[i][1] += enemies[i][4];
    } else if (enemies[i][1] > height - 1) {
      //after the enemies scroll off screen, this value is where they get re-spawned
      enemies[i][1] = -45;
    }
  }
}

//Check for laser collision
function hitTest() {
  var remove = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < lasers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < enemies.length; j++) {
      //laser's y position is less than or equal to the enemy's y position plus its height -AND-
      //laser's x position is greater than or equal to the enemy's x position -AND-
      //laser's x position is less than or equal to the enemy's x position plus it's width
      if (lasers[i][1] <= (enemies[j][1] + enemies[j][3]) && lasers[i][0] >= enemies[j][0] && lasers[i][0] <= (enemies[j][0] + enemies[j][2])) {
        remove = true;
        //draw();//hier explosion afspelen
        enemies.splice(j, 1); //enemy at this array position no longer gets drawn
        enemies.push([(Math.random() * 500) + 50, -45, enemy_w, enemy_h, speed]); //refill a new enemy in a random x position between 50 and 500
      }
    }
    if (remove == true) {
      lasers.splice(i, 1);  //laser at this array position no longer gets drawn
      remove = false;
      score += 10;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code where i define the picture

```
//wereld
var canvas;
var ctx;
var width = 600;
var height = 600;
var starfield;
var starX = 0;
var starY = 0;
var starY2 = -600;

//scoring
var score = 0;
var alive = true;
var lives = 3;
var gameStarted = false;

image = new Image()
image.src = 'explosion.png';

//Clear the canvas, this is required before each canvas frame update
function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

//Initialize image objects, canvas, and event listeners
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  enemy = new Image();
  enemy.src = 'enemy.png';
  ship = new Image();
  ship.src = 'ship.png';
  starfield = new Image();
  starfield.src = 'starfield.jpg';
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('click', gameStart, false);
  gameLoop();
}

//Used by an event listener.  Removes the overall canvas listener once game has started.
function gameStart() {
  gameStarted = true;
  canvas.removeEventListener('click', gameStart, false);
}

//Game loop that calls all the functions needed to be updated
function gameLoop() {
  clearCanvas();
  drawStarfield();
  if (alive && gameStarted && lives > 0) {
    hitTest();
    moveEnemies();
    moveLaser();
    drawEnemies();
    drawShip();
    drawLaser();
    shipCollision();
  }
  scoreTotal();
  //game = setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000 / 30); //not sure why 'game =' is included...
  setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000 / 30); //this works too...
}

//Used to draw several text and shape objects for score, lives, and pre-game information.
function scoreTotal() {
  ctx.font = 'bold 18px VT323';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.fillText('Score: ', 10, 55);
  ctx.fillText(score, 70, 55);
  ctx.fillText('Lives: ', 10, 30);
  ctx.fillText(lives, 68, 30);

  if (!alive) {
    ctx.fillText('Game Over!', 245, (height / 2));

    //Continue button
    ctx.fillRect((width / 2) - 65, (height / 2) + 10, 100, 40);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillText('Opnieuw?', 252, (height / 2) + 35);
    canvas.addEventListener('click', continueButton, false);
  }

  //Pre-Game Text
  if (!gameStarted) {
    ctx.font = 'bold 50px VT323';
    ctx.fillText('Sander Gouman top down', (width / 2) - 210, (height / 2));
    ctx.font = 'bold 20px VT323';
    ctx.fillText('Klik om te spelen', (width / 2) - 56, (height / 2) + 30);
    ctx.fillText('Beweeg met de pijltjes', (width / 2) - 100, (height / 2) + 60);
    ctx.fillText('Gebruik de spatiebalk om te schieten', (width / 2) - 100, (height / 2) + 90);
  }
}

//Used by an event listener.  Detects if mouse click is within a specific area.
function continueButton(e) {
  var cursorPos = getCursorPos(e);
  if (cursorPos.x > (width / 2) - 53 && cursorPos.x < (width / 2) + 47 && cursorPos.y > (height / 2) + 10 && cursorPos.y < (height / 2) + 50) {
    alive = true;
    lives = 3;
    reset();
    canvas.removeEventListener('click', continueButton, false);
  }
}

//Used for detection of mouse click on canvas
function getCursorPos(e) {
  var x;
  var y;

  if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
  } else {
    x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }

  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;
  var cursorPos = new cursorPosition(x, y);

  return cursorPos;
}

//Store x and y cursor position
function cursorPosition(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

//Check lives
function checkLives() {
  lives -= 1;
  if (lives > 0) {
    reset();
  } else if (lives == 0) {
    alive = false;

  }
}

//Reset enemies and player back to default position
function reset() {
  var enemy_reset_x = 50;
  ship_x = (width / 2) - 25;
  ship_y = height - 75;
  ship_w = 50;
  ship_h = 57;

  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    enemies[i][0] = enemy_reset_x;
    enemies[i][1] = -45;
    enemy_reset_x = enemy_reset_x + enemy_w + 60;
  }
}

//Draw a continuous, scrolling starfield (using two instances)
function drawStarfield() {
  ctx.drawImage(starfield, starX, starY);
  ctx.drawImage(starfield, starX, starY2);

  if (starY > 600) {
    starY = -599;
  }

  if (starY2 > 600) {
    starY2 = -599;
  }

  starY += 1;
  starY2 += 1;
}

//Initialize canvas when page is loaded
window.onload = init;
```

Hope you guys can help so i can get more enemy's

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be that, instead of storing enemy attributes in the global scope, consider storing the attributes in an enemy object.

The easiest way to do this is to create a function like

```
 //enemies could be in global scope or 
 //inside a closure that contains everything related to the enemies
var enemies = [];

function spawnenemy(x,y,s,i) {
   var enemy = {
    xcord: x,
    ycord: y,
    speed: s,
    spriteimg: new Image()
   };
   enemy['spriteimg'].src = i;
   enemies.push(enemy);
}
```

and then pass around the each enemy object to your game functions that manipulate your enemy.

for example if you want to change the image of your enemy when it dies have a function like this.

```
function showDead(enemy) {
     //Notice how I am accessing the image property of the enemy...
     enemy['spriteImgUrl'].src = "dead.jpg";
     //do your thing to refresh your canvas to show the new image 
     //or register showDead function with a listener that will do it for you
 }
```

and simply pass the enemy who is supposed to die to this function to show that it's killed.

Hope it gives you ideas.

Comment: i dont really understand it
I made this code with a teacher of mine but i want to finish this myself

Comment: what part don't you understand ?

Comment: i understand the enemies array and then you push an enemy in it
but i dont see where you define that image?

Comment: Sorry, I understood your question now. I made the change to the code accordingly to show how to define image inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend treating each "Enemy" as its own object, and to be able to define objects, you'll want to make your own Enemy class:

```
function Enemy() {
  // stick this at the top of your code somewhere.
  // this defines an Enemy "class", which allows
  // you to make "new" Enemy instances
}
```

Once you have that, you can make "new" enemies and assign them any properties you like... even functions:

```
var enemy1 = new Enemy();
var enemy2 = new Enemy();
enemy1.x = 50;
enemy2.x = 50;
// ... fill in the rest of the stuff here
enemy1.speed = 3;
enemy2.speed = 5;

enemy1.image = new Image();
enemy1.image.src = 'enemyShip1.png';
enemy2.image = new Image();
enemy2.image.src = 'enemyShip2.png';

enemy1.getKilledByPlayer = function() {
  // give the player some score, for example
  // and/or remove this enemy from the game
};

enemies.push(enemy1);
enemies.push(enemy2);
```

The key here is that when you go to draw each enemy, you look up all of its stuff using the object you made (`enemy1`, `enemy2`, or `enemies[i]` if you stick them in an array):

```
function drawEnemies() {
  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(enemies[i].image, enemies[i].x, enemies[i].y);
    // here, saying enemies[i].image is grabbing the exact image you want
    // from when you made enemy1/enemy2 up above
  }
}
```

and since each of the enemies you pushed into the array can have different values for x, y, image, speed, etc... they will all look just the way you want on the screen, depending on what values you gave them to start with.

Comment: hi
when i try your code if i did it the right way
i get this error
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to make a new image for each enemy. I updated my code from above to make a new image for each enemy and then set the "src" just like you were before.

Comment: Hi
Still got the same error i putt my code here that i think it should be hope you can find out what the problem is
http://pastebin.com/p01KPE9r

The error is on line 60

Comment: In your code you have to either push the new way of making enemies onto your array OR the old way. At the moment you are doing both (see lines 43-52)

Comment: hi
when i do that for some reason i dont see any enemy's spawn

Comment: You need to adapt what you've learned here to the rest of your code. For example, in `moveEnemies` you are still using the old way of updating the x and y of each enemy instead of using `enemies[i].x` or `enemies[i].y`.